# Installing Raspbian without recommended Software from NOOBS

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, software-installation, noobs

Is it possible to install Raspbian (without the Recommended software) from NOOBS?

Last time I chose Raspbian from NOOBS installation menu it also included the recommended software (Mathematica, Minecraft etc) - which I don't want.

The reason I want to use NOOBS is I want a dual-boot system with Recalbox.

Comment: Does it have to be installed through NOOBS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget NOOBS use [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md)
 this has a much wider choice of OS - you can install any of the 3 versions of Raspbian.

Each OS has to be downloaded from the web, so PINN doesn't waste the 1.3GB that NOOBS does.